# A while or until loop, until a line with "REMOVE" content in bash. How do I do this?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to grep Ip addresses in a file until line with the "REMOVE" content.
I tried the following thing but the script  gives all IP including after "REMOVE".

```
a="[A-Z]"

cat *.txt| until [[ "$a" =  "REMOVE" ]]; do grep -oE "([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}"; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it with a sed oneliner:

```
sed -n -s -r '1,/REMOVE/ { s/.*(([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}).*/\1/p }' *.txt
```

explanation:

- `-n` makes sed to not print lines unless told explicitly using the `p` command.
- `-s` makes sed handle each file separately instead of combining all files into one stream.
- `-r` makes sed use extended regex syntax which needs less escaping.

note that `-s` and `-r` are gnu extension to sed. if you do not know what gnu extension means then you are most likely using gnu sed. if you are not using a gnu sed then you have to workaround the missing features.

more explanation:

- the sed script `1,/REMOVE/ { commands }` means to execute the commands inside the curly braces from the first line of the input up to the line containing `REMOVE`.
- the sed script `s/pattern/replacement/p` means to search for pattern, replace with replacement and then print that replacement.
- the pattern `.*(([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}).*` is a pattern which recognizes all lines containing a chain of four three digit numbers separated by dots. it also captures the chain in a so called group.
- the back reference `\1` references to the first of the captured groups. this in effect means to discard the rest of the line and print only the ip address.

read the fine [sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) for more explanation. see also the fine [sed tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/sed.html).

Comment: Thanks,this almost works for me. But I have one problem left: The script gives the entire line and I only need the ip address in that line.Example: 123   bla  ip address bla2

Comment: sorry i overlooked that part of your command. please see updated answer.